# Parquet into polars from S3 in Rust: error with CloudOptions

Tags: amazon-s3, rust, rust-polars

I'm completely new to Rust (but experienced coder in general) and I'm struggling with the following problem:

> I want to load a Parquet file stored on a Digital Ocean S3 bucket into a polars `DataFrame` object. (Ideally at a later point I will switch to `LazyFrame`.)

I'm already using `rust-s3` crate to access the S3 successfully, but I'm struggling to find a way to adapt that API to polars (polars seems to be rather opinionated about the backing store being mmap-capable).

I see I may need to use polars own `cloud` module to access the S3 rather than be able to reuse my `rust-s3` code. This is the start of my solution:

```
use polars::prelude::*;


async fn load_dataframe() {
    let uri = "s3://bucket/path";

    let settings = CloudOptions::from_untyped_config(uri, vec![
        ("endpoint_url", "https://ams3.digitaloceanspaces.com".to_string()),
        ("access_key", "elided".to_string()),
        ("secret_key", "elided".to_string()),
    ]);

    let _reader = polars::io::parquet::ParquetAsyncReader::from_uri(uri, Some(settings));
}
```

but this fails to compile with the following error:

```
   Compiling tranquility v0.1.0 (/work)
error[E0599]: no function or associated item named `from_untyped_config` found for struct `hashbrown::map::HashMap` in the current scope
 --> src/trial.rs:7:34
  |
7 |     let settings = CloudOptions::from_untyped_config(uri, vec![
  |                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ function or associated item not found in `hashbrown::map::HashMap<std::string::String, std::string::String, polars::export::ahash::RandomState>`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0599`.
error: could not compile `tranquility` due to previous error
```

I've been going round in circles for several days now trying different ways to approach the broader problem, or work through the specific complier error, but I'm hitting a wall, particularly given how to construct the `CloudOptions` object seems to be undocumented. I've tried ChatGPT too.

Solutions I don't want to consider because they are not compatible with the project requirements:

- Downloading the parquet file to local storage first.

Versions:

- `polars`: 0.28.0 (both polars-core & polars-io)
- `rust-s3`: 0.33.0

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you seen https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/blob/main/examples/read_parquet_cloud/src/main.rs - perhaps it's helpful.